# Why is my Border not displaying although I have set the border-style property to solid?

Tags: html, css, border, code-behind

I have a div on my page which starts out invisible (display:none), but conditionally changes to visible (display:block).

It is defined in html this way, in the aspx file, with display set to none and given a border:

```
<div class="row" id="gadsDiv" runat="server" style="display:none; border-style: solid; margin-top: 
                                                                                            -2px">
    <label style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">GENRES: </label> 
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGenres">None or Unknown</asp:Label><br />
    <label style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">ACTORS: </label> 
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblActors">None or Unknown</asp:Label><br />
    <label style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">DIRECTOR[S]: </label> 
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDirectors">None or Unknown</asp:Label><br />
    <label style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">WRITER[S]: </label> 
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblScreenwriters">None or Unknown</asp:Label>
</div>
```

There is a situation which causes the div to be shown, accomplished by doing this in the code-behind (aspx.cs file):

```
gadsDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;");
gadsDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "border-style:solid;");
gadsDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-top: -2px;");
```

Just to be safe, I re-apply the border-style solid attribute.

But the border does not display (it should be around the GENRES, ACTORS, DIRECTORS, WRITERS section):

[image]

What is preventing the border from displaying?

Comment: Are you setting a width and color on the border as well?

Comment: I have checked the above code block after removing "display:none". it is working. I think you use "border-style:solid" CSS two time. first in inline CSS and second in the below block code.

Comment: I tried your code in local but problem not showing, maybe CSS rules over written by your CSS files. try with important rule e.g. border: 1px solid #000 !important; this will set the CSS specificity to the highest.

Comment: If you can share the live URL it could be easier to debug the issue and help you.

Comment: There is no live URL; this is a work in progress; besides, Tanim already solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `border-style: solid;` use `border: 1px solid #000;` you can change the `px` and color(#000) as you want

Comment: not a big deal, Is it possible to change 1x to 1px? Thanks.